# Gtmetrix : Add Expires headers on my .htaccess, Apache Server ,, here are the results showing the issue and my .htaccess file configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, pagespeed, yslow, gtmetrix

im working on optimizing my website that is hosted on an Apache web server, after working on my css files (combining them in one file ... ) and img alt, optimizing images size and enabling gzip for browsers ,... i got always YSlow Score below to 58% and PageSpeed equal to 80% ,, please need help !

[the image is showing the components that said that they don't have a  "far-future expiration date" (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpefe.png)

this is my .htaccess file where i put some configuration that i found as a solution on Gtmetrix.com

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
#    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}!^www\.exemple\.com

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
#    RewriteRule .* - [S=1]
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#    RewriteRule (.*)http://www.exemple.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>


#******************Non www redirect – Canonical Issue******************





#************"Compressing files / caching"
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent



<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>



<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|css|flv|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|js|pdf|png|svg|swf|tif|tiff|woff|eot|ttif)(\.gz)?$">

        Header set Expires "Thu, 22 Mar 2018 20:00:00 GMT"
        Header unset Etag
        FileETag None

        Header set cache-control "max-age=2592000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i saw the screenshot that you got from Gtmetrix, i think that all is alright with you, and those files are externals,so you can't optimize them :) ! Check other recommendations and try to fix them to get a good YSlow Score, Best Regards Bro :)

Comment: Thanks @midodesign for your answer ,, i had to change my .htaccess config. Now its perfectly workin for me :) Thank u again